URL of Route 53 is not Rendering on IOS devices like iPhone and iPad
I have a route 53 URL https://ss.xyz.com as 'A' record with Route traffic to sdfgvedf.cloudfront.net. this URL is not working in iPhone or iPad or any apple devices but it is working on MacBook so what may be the reason. As we try to hit this https://ss.xyz.com URL it will route to that URL and show the icon in browser tab but the whole page is blank means it is unable to render the index.html page. why it is not able to render and what could be the possible setting can be changed in AWS CloudFront and S3 and Route 53 that make this site index.html render in apple devices.

I don't think that the issue is related to the CloudFront, have you tried checking in other mobile devices other than the Apple devices like Android. If it is not working there too , then the problem is with the webpage itself. Try loading the page in browser and use developer tools to adjust the screen size for different devices.
